# Mysql not writing to binlog

Tags: mysql

Mysql is not writing events to binlog, I have tried change the binlog configurations, but can't solve.

Conf:

```
server_id = 2
log-bin = master
binlog_format = row
replicate-do-db = our_db
log-slave-updates = true
```

'%log%' config:
Seems that log_bin_basename does not exists in 5.5 and log-bin is used to configure the name and automatically turn on the log_bin, but I am still not receiving events in binlog, it just creates the file and write ' master.000919 |   4 | Format_desc |         2 |         107 | Server ver: 5.5.50-0+deb7u2-log, Binlog ver: 4'
    expire_logs_days = 10
    max_binlog_size = 200M
    binlog_do_db = our_db

I also verified that the events are being write to general log

Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

The events that I need to be write in binlog are common inserts.

'%log%' config:

```
Variable_name                            Value                           
back_log                                 50                              
binlog_cache_size                        32768                           
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates  OFF                             
binlog_format                            ROW                             
binlog_stmt_cache_size                   32768                           
expire_logs_days                         10                              
general_log                              OFF                             
general_log_file                         /opt/mysql/SRV01STM085.log      
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           1                               
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog           OFF                             
innodb_log_buffer_size                   8388608                         
innodb_log_file_size                     5242880                         
innodb_log_files_in_group                2                               
innodb_log_group_home_dir                ./                              
innodb_mirrored_log_groups               1                               
log                                      OFF                             
log_bin                                  ON                              
log_bin_trust_function_creators          OFF                             
log_error                                                                
log_output                               FILE                            
log_queries_not_using_indexes            OFF                             
log_slave_updates                        ON                              
log_slow_queries                         OFF                             
log_warnings                             1                               
max_binlog_cache_size                    18446744073709547520            
max_binlog_size                          209715200                       
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size               18446744073709547520            
max_relay_log_size                       0                               
relay_log                                                                
relay_log_index                                                          
relay_log_info_file                      relay-log.info                  
relay_log_purge                          ON                              
relay_log_recovery                       OFF                             
relay_log_space_limit                    0                               
slow_query_log                           OFF                             
slow_query_log_file                      /opt/mysql/SRV01STM085-slow.log 
sql_log_bin                              ON                              
sql_log_off                              OFF                             
sync_binlog                              0                               
sync_relay_log                           0                               
sync_relay_log_info                      0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the 5.5 manual:

> Setting this option causes the log_bin system variable to be set to ON (or 1), and not to the base name. This is a known issue; see Bug #19614 for more information.

Newer versions have made changes in this area, but there continues to be a difference between how the `VARIABLE` `log_bin` (*in my.cnf*) and the commandline `--log-bin` (*when invoking mysqld*).

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-triggers.html :

> With statement-based replication, triggers executed on the master also execute on the slave. With row-based replication, triggers executed on the master do not execute on the slave. Instead, the row changes on the master resulting from trigger execution are replicated and applied on the slave.

Comment: change log-bin to log_bin did not work.

Comment: @GabrielNoth - Different syntax for different places where you set it.  In my.cnf, you need `log_bin=ON` and `log_bin_basename=master`.

Comment: Seems that log_bin_basename does not exists in 5.5 and log-bin is used to configure the name and automatically turn on the log_bin.

Comment: But I am still not receiving events in binlog, it just creates the file and save the event ' master.000919 |   4 | Format_desc |         2 |         107 | Server ver: 5.5.50-0+deb7u2-log, Binlog ver: 4'

Comment: I verified that a query executed by a normal client is write to binlog, but one insert by a trigger isn't. After trying almost every possible solution, I made a trigger that writes the inserts to another table and a Python that delete all registers in that table every second, the delete write in binlog and then I can capture it. I have to turn on log_bin_trust_function_creators also.

Comment: @GabrielNoth - Please update the question to mention that a Trigger is involved.  Then self-Answer your own Question.

Comment: Is there a way to write inserts made by triggers in binlog? I need to replicate them to use with Maxwell's Daemon.

Comment: @GabrielNoth - The manual claims that the trigger's effect will be replicated via "row"; see addition to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but in the really I don't know nor I have control over how the inserts are made, I just did a trigger to write the data to another table, but still don't know how to capture this data in maxwell, or debezium, all of them needs row level replication and I cannot figure out how to write these changes in binlog, except doing a client that modify the table every secod.